# Can we use Data Binding attributes in decision splits in a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

As the title suggests, can we use [Data Binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) attributes in our decision splits?

I have tried testing but all decision paths lead to Remainder because they don't match the criteria.

Comment: Out of curiosity what use case does this solve outside of using journey data or contact data?

Comment: I’m trying to find a particular order status for a record rather than the first one available using contact data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a particular record, I assume you have the UID for this in your Journey Data. Then you can use [Attribute to Attribute Comparison](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5) to find this record in your Contact Data.